# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fromIndex(x) > toIndex(y)

Tags: java

I convert list to `Page` for display table of candidates with pagination,
but I am getting error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fromIndex(5) > toIndex(1)

How to solve this issue?

```
public Page<CandidatesDetailsDto> filterCandidates(Integer page, Integer pageSize) {
    page = (page == null || page < 1) ? 0 : page - 1;
    pageSize = (pageSize == null || pageSize < 1) ? 10 : pageSize;

    PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(page, pageSize);

    List<CandidatesEntity> candidatesEntityList2 = candidatesService.findAll(pageRequest);
   
        int start = (int) pageRequest.getOffset();
        int end = (start + pageRequest.getPageSize()) > candidatesEntityList2.size() ? candidatesEntityList2.size() : (start + pageRequest.getPageSize());

        candidatesEntity = new PageImpl<CandidatesEntity>(candidatesEntityList2.subList(start, end), pageRequest, candidatesEntityList2.size());
    }

    return candidatesEntity.map(source -> candidatesDetailsConverter.convertTo(source));
}
```

Comment: At a certain point, you are doing `candidatesEntityList2.subList(5, 1)`, and that's not legal of course. I recommend to debug for that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception happens because when computing start of your slice you don't take into consideration how many objects are there in full list of candidates.

If I request from your method a page 1 of size 5, but you only have 2 candidates, look what happens:

```
int page = 1;
int pageOffset = 5; // page * pageSize
List<Candidate> all = Arrays.asList(customer1);

int start = 5; // = pageOffset
int end = 1;   // Math.min(start, all.size()); because min(5, 1) == 1.

Page<Candidates> page = new PageImpl(all.subList(start, end)); // this is what throws
```

You have to especially consider the case when someone requested from you the page that does not exist. In that case, you have to either return an empty page, or a `null`, or something else, but important part is it has to be processed on a different code path.

So, here's some code that should *almost* work: you have to implement the `nonExistentPage` method yourself.

```
public Page<CandidatesDetailsDto> filterCandidates(Integer page, Integer pageSize) {

    page = (page == null || page < 1) ? 0 : page - 1;
    pageSize = (pageSize == null || pageSize < 1) ? 10 : pageSize;

    PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(page, pageSize);

    List<CandidatesEntity> candidatesEntityList2 = candidatesService.findAll(pageRequest);

    int start = (int) pageRequest.getOffset();

    if (start <= candidatesEntityList2.size()) {
      return nonExistentPage(candidatesEntityList2.size()); // important part here
    }
    int end = Math.min(start + pageRequest.getPageSize(), candidatesEntityList2.size());

    candidatesEntity = new PageImpl<CandidatesEntity>(candidatesEntityList2.subList(start, end), pageRequest, candidatesEntityList2.size());

    return candidatesEntity.map(source -> candidatesDetailsConverter.convertTo(source));
}

/*
 * Implement this yourself: you must convey to the user that the page 
 * he requested from you does not exist.
 */
private abstract Page<CandidatesDetailsDto> nonExistentPage(int fullListSize);
```

Comment: If your question is solved, please remember to accept an answer. If you know of a better solution, please add that solution as an answer and accept the better one.